# UITextView changing the source text

Tags: iphone, ios, textview, uitextview

How would I make the source text of a UITextView change whenever I press different buttons?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the text of a `UITextView`, set its `text` property:

`textView.text = @"your text here";`

You can call this from within a button's selector like so:

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[yourButton setTitle:@"click to change textview's text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

...

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    textView.text = @"your text";
}
```

Comment: How can I change the text without changing the font and properties?

Comment: @AlbertCatalà: You are probably running into this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049917/uitextview-font-is-being-reset-after-settext

Answer (score 0):

just create different methods which changes the UITextView values. Connect it the correct way in IB to the textView and you're done.