# The UITextView's font is nil, but I set it in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, iboutlet, uifont

SYBListWeiBoCellView is a custom cell and it has a UITextView. I set the font of the UITextview in storyboard, and make a IBOutlet in SYBListWeiBoCellView called repoText.
When I get the SYBListWeiBoCellView through

```
SYBListWeiBoCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"weiboCell"];
UIFont *font = cell.repoText.font;
```

the font turns nil, it should be the value I set in storyboard.

here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115950/1130175 someone say it's a bug.

Comment: Font nil? Can you please elaborate what the problem is?

Comment: ok, the font of UITextView is nil, it should be the value I set in storyboard.

Comment: Are you accessing the UITextfield? Try setting the font using [self.yourTextView setFont:]. I think you are not pointing to the textview reference. Also check whether IBOutlet is connected? Why accessing contentView from cell's reference?

Comment: no, accessing the UITextView.It just a problem that I can't get the attribute that I define in the storyboard. I fix it by checking the "selectedable". I don't konw why it works , someone say it a bug.

Comment: Remove that UITextView and add a new one. Sometimes this happens. I used to get this kinda behavior on UILabels.

Comment: There's 2 approach: (1) Mark the property "selectable" at the TextView element. (2) implement viewWillLayoutSubviews: then setFont at this moment;

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom font, the font you select inside storyboard won't appear inside the application. You have to add the custom font file to your bundle and set the font inside the code.

You may follow this tutorial to add custom fonts: http://www.developers-life.com/how-to-include-ttf-fonts-to-ios-app.html

Comment: The font is not custom.The cell is custom, and the has a UITextView, the font is own to the UITextView.