# Calling setAttributedText on UITextView resets the font size, and I can't figure out why

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I've read about [this annoying bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049917/uitextview-font-is-being-reset-after-settext) on Stackoverflow, where if you don't make your `UITextView` selectable, setting the text will cause the font to reset, which is super annoying.

This seems to only work for when setting the normal `text`, not `attributedText`, because when I set `attributedText` it still resets the font, even if I have my the text view set to selectable.

This is really easy to replicate. Create a text view in a storyboard for instance (how I'm doing it), set a font, then set the attributed text to a plain string with `myTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor.")` and it gets reset.

How do I stop this? It's super annoying.

Comment: Since the font is included in the `NSAttributedString` (with `NSFontAttributedName`), I don't think it's a normal behavior, but at least, I'm not surprised. Maybe by iterating the previous `NSFontAttributedName` of `[myTextView attributedText]` and apply it to the `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it with pragmatism as I'm sure it's a bug in iOS. So, my take might be not the best solution but one that'll work. Write a *category* for `UITextView` where with a method like `-(void)setAttributedTextWithoutResettingFont:(NSAttributedString *)attributedText;` and implement it such that your first save the current font in a temporary variable, then call the actual setter `setAttributedText:` on the `UITextView` and finally update the font again with the one saved in your temporary variable.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you mean by this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: well, which part don't you understand? :) do you know what a category is?