# Text view loses tint color after dismissing an alert view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uialertcontroller

I found a bug in iOS and I'm wondering if there is a workaround.

If you select a `UITextView` with a tint color and while it's selected you display a `UIAlertController` such as by tapping on a navigation bar button item the `UITextView` loses it's tint color after dismissing the `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Where are you setting the text views tint color? In code or in the storyboard? Does the UIAlertController have an action? You can reset the tint color of the textview in the alert's completion block.

Comment: It's set programmatically but happens regardless if the tintColor property is set directly or using the appearance API.  I tried resetting the tint color again in the completion block but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, @Berry Blue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I filed and submitted a bug report with a sample project but haven't had any response after that.  I would file a bug and reference my submitted bug #22879488.

Answer (score 0):

[Please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115950/3288182). And also, like +lostAtSeaJoshua said, you can declare a simple method to reset the tint color of your UITextView after executing (or after clicking a confirm button) your UIAlertController.